# Unable to click on logo , CSS issue

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
 <div class="app-header-logo">
        <a href="/home"><img ng-src="img/..."/></a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.app-header-logo {
    width: 48px;
    height: 64px;
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px 16px 0px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #009530;
    display: inline-block;
}

    .app-header-logo > img {
        height: 32px;
        margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
    }
```

Above is my code , I want when user clicks on image he must be redirected to some link, but when I am inspecting the element I see that anchor tag is there but I am not able to click, I do not know too much of CSS but I hope this is CSS issue.

Because when I remove the above class `"app-header-logo"` I am able to click and also icon - cursor:pointer is getting displayed.

Any help is appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: Can you show full html and css code? It's looks like something is positioned over your logo. If you show your code we can reproduce error and then find solution

Comment: what happen when you click on logo does it show any `404` error or no reaction

Comment: right now nothing happens when I click on logo and its like logo is disabled. even no pointer(hand icon) display when I hover to that image

Comment: @shreyansh does logo is displayed..?

Comment: Right click on logo and then look what element highlighted in the DOM. That element located over link and logo. Then check styles of that element. maybe simple 
.app-header-logo{position:relative.z-index:9999999; .....another styles}

Comment: yes, it is getting displayed and one thingI noticed when I am inspecting the element it comes to some other div, I have to go up to see my logo and there i see the anchor tag is getting attached with it

Comment: @shreyansh there is no issue in your code or css but there is no content in anchor tag so it in not visible and it height and width is "0" check i have posted code it may help you.

Comment: @ AlmasK89 Thanks a lot you solved my problem.

Comment: @shreyansh You are welcome)

Comment: @shreyansh Can you provide demo like jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

now try to this css

```
.app-header-logo a {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

and remove to `>`  this

```
.app-header-logo  img {
        height: 32px;
        margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
    }
```

or define to this

```
.app-header-logo a {display:block;}
```

`a` is inline element define it's **block** lever or **inline-block** level element.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/4cedfvdk/

```
 //CSS
 .app-header-logo {
width: 48px;
height: 64px;
padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
margin: 0px 16px 0px 0px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
background-color: #009530;
display: inline-block;
```

}

```
.app-header-logo img {
    height: 32px;
    margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
    width:32px;
}
.app-header-logo img:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}


//HTML
<div class="app-header-logo">
       <a target=-blank href="https://www.google.com.pk/"><img     src="http://www.picdesi.com/upload/comment/friend/best-friends-quote-pic.jpg"/>   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your Js fiddle is empty and also the solution which you provided not working

Comment: check it now jsfiddle link not saved

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code here you just need to add padding to a link.

```css
.app-header-logo {
  width: 48px;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
  margin: 0px 16px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #009530;
  display: inline-block;
}

.app-header-logo > img{
  height: 32px;
  margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
}
.app-header-logo>a{ padding : 4px 20px 50px 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="app-header-logo">
  <a href="/home"><img ng-src="img/..."/></a>
</div>
```